# Jquery: Prevent reloading page when pressing input type=submit

Tags: jquery, post, input, submit, double

I have the following code in a MVC 3 (Razor) project:

```
<div class="user_info" id="id_user_info">
   <script type="text/ecmascript"  >
      $(function () {
         $('#buttonClear').live('submit', function (e) { return false; });
         $('#buttonClear').bind('click', function () {
            $('username').value = "";
            $('password').value = "";
         });
   </script>
   @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "loginForm" }))
   {
      <label for="username">Enter:</label>
      <input name="username" id="username" type="text" value="" /><br />
      <input name="password" id="password" type="password" value="" /><br />
      <input name="rememberMe" id="rememberMe" type="checkbox" value="true" />
      <label for="rememberMe">Remember me?</label><br />
      <input id="buttonLogin" type='submit' value="Login" />
      <input id="buttonClear" type='submit' value="Clear" />
   }
</div>
```

I need to keep the "buttonClear as type sumbit because of the style, but i need to disable/avoid/prevent it from reloading the page once pressed.

Is there a way to remove the "submit event" from "buttonClear"?

Thanks
Ricardo

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$('#buttonClear').click(function(e){
  // do whatever actions you need here
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thank you, i had to change the actions to: $('#username').val(""); $('#password').val("");

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest removing the handler you're binding to the `submit` event, and instead using `preventDefault` in the `click` event handler:

```
$('#buttonClear').bind('click', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $('username').value = "";
   $('password').value = "";
});
```

The `submit` event approach you have tried will not work because `submit` events can only be bound to `form` elements, not the buttons that submit the form.

Comment: Thank you, i had to change the actions to: $('#username').val(""); $('#password').val("");

Answer (score 2):

try  `e.preventDefault();`

```
   $('#buttonClear').bind('click', function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $('username').value = "";
       $('password').value = "";
    });
```

Comment: Thank you, i had to change the actions to: $('#username').val(""); $('#password').val("");

Answer (score 1):

While I realize this post is a little older, I wanted to provide this answer for the record as well.

> ```
> <input id="buttonClear" type='submit' value="Clear" />
> ```

Normally you would not have multiple submit buttons for one form. Additionally, since you don't actually want submit functionality it wouldn't be accurate to use this type. Finally you are looking for a "Clear" or "Reset" functionality. Your button should be:

```
<input id="buttonClear" type="reset" value="Clear" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just

```
$('#buttonClear').click(function() {
    return false;
});
```