# unable to access click event of a button in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to access the click event of an element on my HTML page.

So, in chrome, I right-clicked the element -> selected Inspect element and got the following

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="ben-count-submit">Update</button>
```

I then went to a js page and wrote the following

```
$("#ben-count-submit").click(function () {      
        console.log("clicked on the update button");
    });
```

However, when I click on the button, I don't see any console log. It just takes me back to the home page of the web site and shows the url as the start page of the site appended with a '?' at the end as follows

```
http://localhost/myproject/start/?
```

How do I access the click event of this button? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery: Prevent reloading page when pressing input type=submit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6704548/jquery-prevent-reloading-page-when-pressing-input-type-submit)

Comment: Sometimes you need reload the page, doing it you can change everyhthing.

Comment: If you are submiting form than use onsubmit function in form tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your button is `submit` type, the button causes page refresh, you need to use `preventDefault()`.

```
$("#ben-count-submit").click(function (event) {      
      event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: thanks. It worked. I can't upvote since I don't have the reputation. Will come back when I have enough points.

Comment: @saltandwater do not wory, happy to help!